# Correct way to protect a private API Key when versioning a python application on a public git repo

Tags: python, version-control, configuration

I would like to open-source a python project on Github but it contains an API key that should not be distributed.
I guess there's something better than removing the key each time a "push" is committed to the repo.

Imagine a simplified `foomodule.py` :

```
import urllib2
API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXXX'
urllib2.urlopen("http://example.com/foo?id=123%s" % API_KEY ).read()
```

What i'm thinking is:

1. Move the API_KEY in a second `key.py` module importing it on `foomodule.py`; i would then add `key.py` on `.gitignore` file.
2. Same as 1. but using `ConfigParser`

Do you know any good programmatic way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a versioned template `key_template.py`:

```
domain = 'example.com'
API_KEY =
```

Check it out to local machine, fill sensitive fields (such as `API_KEY`) and save as `key.py`. Ignore `key.py` in your version-control software. It really doesn't matter if you keep it in Python files or use `ConfigParser`.

Automatic way might be to auto-merge on update with the existing `key.py` file.

Comment: Uhm, i don't get it; which key file do you import into foomodule.py?

Comment: @Silent so, checkout key.py with empty value and then ignore from version-control?

Comment: No check out version-controlled template (`key_template.py`), fill the fields and save as `key.py`. Ignore `key.py`

Comment: Sorry, i'm lost; if somebody will clone my repo, how could be work on import if key.py is missing?

Comment: @system: `except ImportError: print instructions`?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to make it an explicit part of the interface. Make it an argument for your object constructors, for example. Or require the client to extend your class and provide a method, returning the key.
It sucks when one needs to edit your module before she can use it.